# How do I create a PDF with base64 string from a GET request

Tags: php, laravel

```
$response = Http::get('$url')['file'];
$response = base64_decode($response);
Storage::disk('public')->put('file56.pdf', $response);
Storage::disk('custom-ftp')->putFileAs('/Kunde1/', $response, 'test2.pdf');
```

I get a `Base64` string as response from the GET request. With a tool on the internet I can turn the `Base64` string into a PDF. In the code I save the file in the storage folder . But how can I send the file via FTP now? I can upload a file via FTP if I use a form. But I get the following error message with the code posted above.

> Error: "fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for "[How to configure the FTP driver](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#driver-prerequisites)"

Comment: No I have configured the FTP driver. I can upload a file via FTP if I use a form. But I get the following error message with the code posted above. 
"fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given"

Comment: Shouldn't that be in your question?

Comment: Yes I have updated the question

Comment: I'd suggest to debug the error. What is given exactly to `fopen`? If I read the documentation, you should pass `new Illuminate\Http\File($path)` to the `putFileAs` method (use the `public` disk): https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#storing-files

Comment: Yah as @Rolf said. I think you can just use ```Storage::disk('custom-ftp')->put('/Kunde1/test2.pdf', $response);```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I have now used the put() instead of putFileAs() function.